# Spring xml bean definition overriding

Tags: java, spring

I have a project **Ext** that extends another spring project **Root**.
In **Root** project there is a bean defined in xml and it contains property setter:

```
<bean id="bean" class="com.company.root.BeanClass">
    <property name="propertiesList">
        <list>
            <value>com.company.root.ValueA</value>
            <value>com.company.root.ValueB</value>
            <value>com.company.root.ValueC</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I override this definition and add one more value to propertiesList setter?
2. Can I replace `com.company.root.ValueA` class to `com.company.ext.ExtValueA` in my project?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using BeanFactoryPostProcessor. It has access to BeanFactory, that contains all bean definitions, so I just get bean definition I need and change its configuration metadata.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).